# jsf align checkboxes in panelgrid

Tags: html, css, jsf

Hello I have a form that is rendered with a `panelgrid` with 3 columns like this:

> Label-InputField-ErrorMessage

I want to add some checkboxes but I have trouble with the alignment.

```
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
            <h:outputText value="Όνομα:"></h:outputText>
            <h:inputText id="name" value="#{regBean.name}" required="true"
                requiredMessage="Παρακαλώ εισάγετε όνομα!"
            >
                <f:validator validatorId="nameValidator" />
            </h:inputText>
            <h:message id="namemsg" for="name" style="color:red"></h:message>

            <h:outputText value="Επώνυμο:"></h:outputText>
            <h:inputText id="surname" value="#{regBean.surname}" required="true"
                requiredMessage="Παρακαλώ εισάγετε επώνυμο"
            >
                <f:validator validatorId="nameValidator" />
            </h:inputText>
            <h:message for="surname" style="color:red"></h:message>
<h:outputText value="Ενδιφέρομαι για"></h:outputText>
            <h:selectManyCheckbox>

                <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Number1 - 1" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Number1 - 2" />

                <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Number1 - 3" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="4" itemLabel="Number1 - 4" />

            </h:selectManyCheckbox>

            <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Submit"></h:commandButton>
            <h:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset"></h:commandButton>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Without selectboxes:
[image]

This is what I get when I add them:
[image]

I want something like this:

[image]

I tried adding html tags inside the `h:panelGrid` but it failed. Is there any way to achieve it only with css/html/jsf?

Thx in advnace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was easier than I thought. I had to add `layout="pageDirection"` at the `<h:selectManyCheckbox>` and wrap the selections in a `panelGroup`

The fixed code:

```
<h:outputText value="Ενδιαφέρομαι για"></h:outputText>
        <h:panelGroup layout="block">
            <h:selectManyCheckbox layout="pageDirection">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Item 1" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Item 2" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="3" itemLabel="Item 3" />
                <f:selectItem itemValue="4" itemLabel="Item 4" />
            </h:selectManyCheckbox>
        </h:panelGroup>
```